How to recover 'my iphone' directory and files?
I wanted to install the available iOS update on my iPhone 11. I did not have enough space available, so I got to the 'storage' part of the settings menu where all the apps are listed and the storage space they are using.
I also got in the 'my iPhone' directory, and somehow, I accidentally removed the 'Files' directory (or the directory that is/was listed there) because I tapped the wrong small icon.


I had about 238mb of data/files in that directory and I would like to recover it. Is there any way I can recover these files? Going into 'recently deleted' doesn't help as there are only few files in.

Easiest way may to be to restore from backup.

Deleting from iPhone's storage management in Settings skips the Recently Deleted folder.
You need to restore from backup.
